# mongodb $slice, can the default ordering of embedded elements post slicing be changed?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am using the mongodb slice operator to return only the last 5 embedded documents from an array of 10 embedded documents which works fine,
but the order in which i get the last 5 embedded documents is like '6, 7, 8, 9, 10'. what if i want the same embedded documents to be returned in this order '10, 9, 8, 7, 6'.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about slice projection:

```
> db.test.drop()
> db.test.insert({ "_id" : 0, "x" : [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] })
> db.test.find({ "_id" : 0 }, { "x" : { "$slice" : -5 } })
{ "_id" : 0, "x" : [6, 7, 8, 9, 10] }
```

then no, you cannot reorder the array before it is returned to you. You can do so afterwards, in client code, or you can, e.g., iterate it in reverse to see the element in the order 10, 9, 8, 7, 6.

You can also try to maintain the array in the order that you want the elements to be in when they are returned. If that's decreasing order, just use [`$sort`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/#up._S_sort) with `$push` and `$each` in updates:

```
> db.test.drop()
> db.test.insert({ "_id" : 0, "x" : [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] })
> db.test.update({ "_id" : 0 },
                 { "$push" : { "x" : { "$each" : [9, 10], "$sort" : -1 | | |)
> db.test.findOne()
{ "_id" : 0, "x" : [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0] }
> db.test.find({ "_id" : 0 }, { "x" : { "$slice" : 5 } })
{ "_id" : 0, "x" : [10, 9, 8, 7, 6] }
```